# Запись действий пользователя в браузере

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Добрый день!

Необходимо сделать рекордер действий пользователя в браузере (клик по элементу, переход на другую страницу, ввод данных в поле ввода и пр.).

Пробовал первый вариант - использовал Selenium driver. Запускал браузер, потом инжектил JS-события в док сайта, при совершении события JS отправлял кросс-доменный запрос к localhost:[someport]. 
Данный метод не взлетел, потому что на некоторых сайтах имеется защита и при отправке запроса - он блокируется(к примеру на mail.ru). (Кстати, если знаете как с этой проблемой побороться, то буду благодарен за помощь)

Отсюда вопрос: какие ещё могут быть варианты записи действий в браузере?

Selenium IDE не предлагать, нужно без установки расширений для браузера и с использованием нескольких браузеров(не только firefox).

Спасибо!

Comment: О какой защите речь?

Comment: @andreymal: CSP обойти не могу, блокирует запросы через XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Сервер-то отдаёт нужные Allow-заголовки? Скорее всего это именно localhost запрещает обращаться к себе со страницы mail.ru, а не наоборот. CORS и всё такое

Comment: У меня мой localhost - это HTTPListener в c#. Без доп настроек. Я так понимаю, что если бы это была проблема в сервере, то никакой запрос не проходил бы, но с других сайтов запросы успешно проходят.

Ошибка следующая: 
Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:51025/Click' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src mail.ru *.mail.ru *.imgsmail.ru *.mradx.net *.gemius.pl *.weborama.fr *.adriver.ru *.serving-sys.com *.moatads.com". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Я что-то неправильно вкуриваю?

Answer (score 1):

Без установки расширений скорее всего никак. Вы не можете просто так взять и перехватить действия пользователя из вне, без ведома самого пользователя, если сможете так сделать, считайте, что нашли уязвимость браузера.

Comment: Яндекс.Метрика оказывается работает на уязвимостях, вот это новость

Comment: Яндекс.Метрика требует установки кода в сам сайт. Если вы убедите к примеру mail.ru встроить ваш код, то тогда без проблем.

Comment: Со встраиванием проблем нет, автор через Selenium творит что хочет